# Can I make a Gear vr application in Android Studio with Vuforia?

Tags: android, gear-vr

Can I run the vufoira sample applications for the gear vr in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you can.

Vuforia wants be a partner with vr. It already has cardboard vuforia vr/ar demos.